# How to measure scanf time in a C program?

Tags: c

In the following program, I want to measure the input time i.e. the time taken by user to enter the variables of the array :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>

int main()
{
    int i, array[10];
    double user_input_time;
    clock_t input_start, input_end;

    input_start = clock();

    for (i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        scanf("%d", &array[i]);
    }

    input_end = clock();

    user_input_time = ((double)(input_end - input_start)) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC;

    printf("User Input Time : %f\n", user_input_time);

    return 0;
 }
```

Above, what I'm getting is the processor time taken not the input time taken by user to enter all the 10 variable of the array.

Please, can someone help me in doing so.

Comment: I'm extremely sorry for not adding the part that I have already tried.

Comment: You can use [`clock_gettime`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/clock_gettime.2.html) if you have it.

Comment: Your code works fine here. What is your platform? What is `CLOCKS_PER_SEC` on your platform. What value is displayed if the user input takes say 10 seconds?

Comment: @MichaelWalz I'm running this C program on Linux. My output is 0.000017

Comment: @MichaelWalz If `clock` returns wall clock time on your platform, your standard library is broken.

Comment: @melpomene yes, that's why it works here. Thanks.

Comment: @melpomene Thanks for helping me.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Include: `time.h`

Use:

```
int main()
{
    time_t start = time(NULL);
    //Do your operations here
    printf("%.2f\n", (double)(time(NULL) - start));

    return 0;
}
```

**Note** -  We can use `clock_gettime` for more precise results - [link](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/clock_gettime.2.html)

---

**Using `clock_gettime`**

```
int main () { 
    struct timespec start, finish; 
    clock_gettime(CLOCK_REALTIME, &start); 

    // do your operations here

    clock_gettime(CLOCK_REALTIME, &finish); 

    long seconds = finish.tv_sec - start.tv_sec; 
    long ns = finish.tv_nsec - start.tv_nsec; 

    if (start.tv_nsec > finish.tv_nsec) { // clock underflow 
    --seconds; 
    ns += 1000000000; 
    } 
    printf("seconds without ns: %ld\n", seconds); 
    printf("nanoseconds: %ld\n", ns); 
    printf("total seconds: %e\n", (double)seconds + (double)ns/(double)1000000000); 
}
```

Comment: `clock` measures CPU time, not wallclock time. This is exactly the wrong thing to use for measuring user actions.

Comment: edited it for user time! didn't notice it before. thanks

Comment: Note that on many common platforms, `time` returns whole seconds only.

Comment: what does time(NULL) do?

Comment: We can use  gettimeofday for that @melpomene

Comment: You can pass in a pointer to a time_t object that time will fill up with the current time (and the return value is the same one that you pointed to). If you pass in NULL, it just ignores it and merely returns a new time_t object that represents the current time.

Comment: @AbhishekKeshri "*POSIX.1-2008 marks `gettimeofday()` as obsolete, recommending the use of `clock_gettime(2)` instead.*" http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/gettimeofday.2.html

Comment: I'm sorry but can you please tell me how to use clock_gettime()

Comment: yeah sure, give me a minute]

Answer (score 1):

Which precision do you want ?

Because you can use simply `time(NULL)` if you only want to know the time at the second.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>

int main(void)
{
    int i, array[10];
    time_t user_input_time, input_start, input_end;

    input_start = time(NULL);

    for (i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        scanf("%d", &array[i]);
    }

    input_end = time(NULL);

    user_input_time = input_end - input_start;

    printf("User Input Time : %d second\n", (int)user_input_time);

    return 0;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `gettimeofday()` from `sys/time.h`

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/time.h>

int main(void)
{
  int i, array[10];
  struct timeval input_start, input_end;

  gettimeofday(&input_start, NULL);

  for (i = 0; i < 10; i++)
  {
    scanf("%d", &array[i]);
  }

  gettimeofday(&input_end, NULL);

  printf("User Input Time : %d second\n", input_end.tv_sec - input_start.tv_sec);

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: That doesn't look like the right way to use a `struct timeval`.